# How do I autoplay audio after autoplay policy got changed?

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble getting a mp3 file to autoplay. My div with the mp3 file is called "lyd".

Tried making it in js, but it didn't work.

```
let lyd = document.getElementById("lyd");
lyd.play();
```

It doesn't output the sound.

HTML

```
<audio type="audio/mpeg" id="lyd" src="../music/Space.mp3"></audio>
```

The error in my console is:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Comment: @CodeF0x <audio type="audio/mpeg" id="lyd" src="../music/Space.mp3"></audio> The error in my console is: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Comment: It's working on other browser ?

Comment: (Fortunately) some browsers block music to be auto-played

Comment: Adding the `muted` attribute to your audio element might help. The audio should get started then automatically via your code (but muted, obviously). Simply unmute it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some browsers block music to be auto-played. For Chrome, they changed `autoplay` [policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes). So, You should always look at the Promise returned by the play function to see if it was rejected:

```js
var lyd = document.getElementById( 'lyd' );
var promise = lyd.play();

if ( promise !== undefined ) {
  promise.then(_ => {
    // Autoplay started!
  } ).catch( error => {
      // Autoplay was prevented.
      // Show a "Play" button so that user can start playback.
      var btn = document.getElementById( 'btnPlay' );

      btn.style.visibility = 'visible'
      btn.onclick = function() {
      lyd.play()
    }
  } );
}
```

```css
#btnPlay {
  visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<audio type="audio/mpeg" id="lyd" src="https://www.zapsplat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/sound-effects-two/musical_compressed_house_or_trance_drum_loop.mp3"></audio>

<input id="btnPlay" name="" type="button" value="Play Sound">
```

It still throws an error into console, but at least the audio is playing.